# How to conditionally download file using p:fileDownload

Tags: primefaces

A file has to be downloaded conditionally. When the button is clicked, the data is fetched from the database. The data is validated. If the data is valid (#{reportPage.validData}) the file is created & downloaded.
However, if the data is invalid, the file is not to be downloaded.  As per my understanding fileDownload has 2 attributes: value; contextDisposition. How can I download the file conditionally ?

```
   <p:commandButton id="generaterReport" ajax="false" 
     value="#{msg['report.generateReport']}" actionListener="#{reportPage.onGenerateReport}"> 
        <p:fileDownload value ="#{reportPage.csvFile}" />
    </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: If validation fails simply make sure that `#{reportPage.csvFile} resolves to nothing?

Comment: Might as well mark it as an answer then? ;)

Comment: Also though, the validation data you're referring to - is it coming from the database or is it coming from user input? If it's user input that you need to validate, there are better ways of doing this.

Comment: No, I need to validate data from the data base.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, but ok, glad it worked.

Answer (score 4):

If validation fails simply make sure that `#{reportPage.csvFile} resolves to nothing.